# SQL, Find if a column in any of my tables has some info

Tags: sql

I'm kind of new using SQL, but I keep learning. 
Right now I have the challenge to compare some information from diferent sources.
But I have the idea that we have the data into some tables. The real problem is I have no idea which table could have the info.

The data I'm searching is like this always : HA00XXXX

Where X is a number.

Any of you guys, know a way to look into all the tables if there is a column with this format? As far as I know there is the command "like" that I could use when I know which table.

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Comment: You do not know which table, you do not know which column in this unknown table and you do not know the exact thing you are looking for? Beside that its all just "an idea" so you dont even have the data or the db or the tables? Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your ideas. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is about concrete questions that can be answered.

Comment: You can build dynamic querys using the schema information. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza he would have to at first consolidate his "sources" into some tables ...

Comment: I don't know why I thought this was PostgreSQL (maybe was because the previous question I answer) So every rdbms have a different way to get the fields from the tables.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+search+all+columns